# Sinatra: Why is this a syntax error?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra

I am creating a CRUD API using Ruby, Sinatra, and MongoDB. I keep getting the following error message and I can't figure out what I've done wrong:

> SyntaxError: /yasi.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}' Yasi.connect {:server => "localhost", :db => "yasi"} ^ /yasi.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}' Yasi.connect {:server => "localhost", :db => "yasi"} ^

Here is what my code looks like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'lib/yasi'

before do
  Yasi.connect {:server => "localhost", :db => "yasi"}
end

get "/" do
  @yasis = Yasi.find :all
  erb :index
end

get "/new" do
  erb :new
end

get "/delete/:id" do
  Yasi.delete(params[:id])
  redirect "/"
end

post "/" do
  params.reject! {|k,v| k == "submit"}
  Yasi.save(params)
  redirect "/"
end
```

Here is the lib/yasi file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'
require 'sinatra'

module Yasi
  class << self

def connect(config)
    @db = Mongo::Connection.new(config[:server],config[:port] || 27017).db(config[:db])
end 

def find(search)
  if search == :all
    #return all
    yasi = @db.collection("yasis").find.to_a
    return nil_or_array(yasi)
  else 
    return find_with_criteria(search)
  end
end  

def save(yasi)
    stringify_keys(yasi)
    #handle author first
    if yasi["author"]
        stringify_keys(yasi["author"])
    author = @db.collection("authors").find_one(yasi["author"])
    unless author 
        author = @db.collection("authors").save(yasi["author"])
    end
    yasi["author"] = author 
  end

  @db.collection("yasis").save(yasi)    
end  

def delete(id)
  victim = @db.collection("yasis").find_one(Mongo::ObjectID.from_stringid))
  @db.collection("yasis").remove(victim) if victim
end     


private

def find_with_criteria(search)
  stringify_keys(search)
  if search["author"]
    author = @db.collection("authors").find_one stringify_keys(search["author"])
    if author
        search[:author] = author
        yasi = @db.collection("yasis").find(search).to_a
        return nil_or_array yasi
    else 
        nil
    end
  else 
    yasi = @db.collection("yasis").find(search).to_a
    return nil_or_array(yasi)
  end       
end 

def stringify_keys(hash)
  hash.each_key do |key|
    hash[key.to_s] = hash.delete(key)
  end
  hash  
end 

def nil_or_array(result)
  if result.size == 0
    return nil
  else 
    return result
  end   
  end   

end     
end
```

Comment: Do you mind pasting the `lib/yasi` file in here as well?

Comment: I didn't think that would be causing the problem, but sure.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things. Make sure you're accessing `yasi` in the correct path. Also, pass a variable referencing your hash as `config` to `Yasi.connect` like below:

```
require './lib/yasi'

before do
  config = { :server => "localhost", :db => "yasi" }
  Yasi.connect config
end
```

That should handle the error you've posted about, but I would also double check your indentation in the yasi file to make it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: That worked, but now I'm getting this error:  uninitialized constant Mongo::Connection

Comment: Do you have `mongo` installed locally?

Comment: Yes, it's installed.